# How to set Master address for Spark examples from command line

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

**NOTE:** *They author is looking for answers to set the Spark Master when running Spark examples that involves **no** changes to the source code, but rather only options that can be done from the command-line if at all possible.*

Let us consider the run() method of the BinaryClassification example:

```
  def run(params: Params) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"BinaryClassification with $params")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Notice that the SparkConf did not provide any means to configure the SparkMaster.

When running this program from Intellij with the following arguments:

```
--algorithm LR --regType L2 --regParam 1.0 data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt
```

the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set
in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.BinaryClassification$.run(BinaryClassification.scala:105)
```

I have also tried adding in the Spark Master url anyways (though the code seems NOT to support it ..)

```
  spark://10.213.39.125:17088   --algorithm LR --regType L2 --regParam 1.0 
  data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt
```

and

```
--algorithm LR --regType L2 --regParam 1.0 spark://10.213.39.125:17088
data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt
```

Both do not work with error:

```
Error: Unknown argument 'data/mllib/sample_binary_classification_data.txt'
```

For reference here is the options parsing - which does nothing with SparkMaster:

```
val parser = new OptionParser[Params]("BinaryClassification") {
  head("BinaryClassification: an example app for binary classification.")
  opt[Int]("numIterations")
    .text("number of iterations")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(numIterations = x))
  opt[Double]("stepSize")
    .text(s"initial step size, default: ${defaultParams.stepSize}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(stepSize = x))
  opt[String]("algorithm")
    .text(s"algorithm (${Algorithm.values.mkString(",")}), " +
    s"default: ${defaultParams.algorithm}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(algorithm = Algorithm.withName(x)))
  opt[String]("regType")
    .text(s"regularization type (${RegType.values.mkString(",")}), " +
    s"default: ${defaultParams.regType}")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(regType = RegType.withName(x)))
  opt[Double]("regParam")
    .text(s"regularization parameter, default: ${defaultParams.regParam}")
  arg[String]("<input>")
    .required()
    .text("input paths to labeled examples in LIBSVM format")
    .action((x, c) => c.copy(input = x))
```

So .. yes .. I could go ahead and modify the source code.  But I suspect instead I am missing an *available* tuning knob to make this work that does not involve modifying the source code.

Comment: By reading comments, you say you did not want answers that modify the source code. You "kinda" say something about that you COULD modify the source code, but then you basically ask for options to fix the problem. You never ask your direct question nor do you rule out source code, yet you then yell at everyone who answers your question that are along the lines of "I could go ahead and modify the source code" which opens up that door and surely doesn't close it.  "But I suspect instead I am missing an available tuning knob to make this work." is not a question, nor rules out source modification.

Comment: I edited the question to make this clear and avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can set the Spark master from the command-line by adding the JVM parameter:

```
-Dspark.master=spark://myhost:7077
```

Comment: works with Spark 1.6 as well (tested from Eclipse Scala IDE)

Answer (score 42):

If you want to get this done from code you can use `.setMaster(...)` when creating the `SparkConf`:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
                          .setMaster("spark://myhost:7077")
```

**Long overdue EDIT** (as per the comments)

For the session in Spark 2.x +:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .appName("app_name")
                        .getOrCreate()
```

Command line (2.x) assuming local standalone cluster.

```
spark-shell --master spark://localhost:7077
```

Comment: The OP said **without changing source code** -- which you did here.

Comment: @javadba your question wasn't worded clearly, I can see why people made this error.  Editing the question to make it clear what you were asking along with the restrictions you had in mind.

Answer (score 14):

I downloaded Spark 1.3.0 and wanted to test the java samples using Eclipse Luna 4.4 and found out that to run the java samples you need to add spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar as a referenced library to your Java project.

The fastest way to start with Spark using Java is to run the JavaWordCount example. 
To fix above issue add following line for Spark configuration:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
```

And that's it, try running using Eclipse you should get success. If you see below error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
```

just ignore, scroll the console down and you'll see your input text file line per line followed by a counter of words.

This is a fast way to get started on Spark with Windows OS without worrying to get Hadoop installed, you just need JDK 6 and Eclipse

Comment: The OP said **without changing source code**  -- which you did here.

Answer (score 5):

as the document mentioned:
`setMaster(String master)`

The master URL to connect to, such as `local` to run locally with one thread, `local[4]` to run locally with 4 cores, or `spark://master:7077` to run on a Spark standalone cluster.

Comment: The OP said **without changing source code** -- which you did here.

Answer (score 5):

So here is the solution.

1. Set as Local with 1 thread by default

   ```
   new SparkConf().setAppName("Ravi Macha").setMaster("local")
   ```
2. Or with arguments (i.e. number of threads in brackets)

   ```
   new SparkConf().setAppName("Ravi Macha").setMaster("local[2]")
   ```

Comment: Please READ the question: it says *from the **command line*** . In any case an answer meeting the requirements has been provided - and accepted -  almost two years ago.