# Understanding spark --master

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have simple spark app that reads master from a config file:

```
new SparkConf()
  .setMaster(config.getString(SPARK_MASTER))
  .setAppName(config.getString(SPARK_APPNAME))
```

What will happen when ill run my app with as follow:

```
spark-submit --class <main class> --master yarn <my jar>
```

Is my master going to be overwritten?

I prefer having the master provided in standard way so I don't need to maintain it in my configuration, but then the question how can I run this job directly from IDEA? this isn't my application argument but spark-submit argument.

Just for clarification my desired end product should:

- when run in cluster using --master yarn, will use this configuration
- when run from IDEA will run with local[*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not set the master into your code.
2. In production  you could use the option `--master` of `spark-submit` which will tell spark which master to use (yarn in you case). also the value of `spark.master` in spark-defaults.conf file will do the job (priority is for `--master`  and then the property in configuration file)
3. In an IDEA... well I know in Eclipse you could pass a VM argument in Run Configuration `-Dspark.master=local[*]` for example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24481688/1314742). 
   In IDEA I think it is not too much different, you could check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-application.html) to add VM options