# Running Apache Spark Example Application in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run the SparkPi.scala example program in Netbeans. Unfortunately I am quite new to Spark and have not been able to execute it successfully.

My preference is to work in Netbeans only and execute from there. I know spark also allows executing from the spark console - I however prefer not to take that approach.

This is my build.sbt file contents:

```
name := "SBTScalaSparkPi"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
```

This is my plugins.sbt file contents:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
```

This is the program I am trying to execute:

```
import scala.math.random

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

/** Computes an approximation to pi */
object SparkPi {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
    val count = spark.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
        val x = random * 2 - 1
        val y = random * 2 - 1
        if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
      }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

JDK version: 1.8.

The error I get when trying to execute the code is given below:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/03/25 07:50:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/03/25 07:50:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/03/25 07:50:26 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:401)
at SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
16/03/25 07:50:26 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>
at SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:28)
at SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you read the error message: "A master URL must be set in your configuration". Is a master URL set in your configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am not sure what master URL to set - for the Hadoop installation. Does Spark then rely on Hadoop? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Master address for spark 1.X examples from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481399/how-to-set-master-address-for-spark-1-x-examples-from-command-line)

Comment: In general Spark does not rely on Hadoop however oftentimes both systems are rolled out on the same infrastructure. This proves convenient and performant because Spark RRDs can pull data from Hadoop's HDFS.

Comment: here is the answer of your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35902986/1314742

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A master URL must be set in your configuration

You must set a `spark.master` in your SparkConf. There are only two mandatory parameters you must set - the master and the AppName that you've already set. For more details, see [Initializing Spark section](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#initializing-spark) in the docs.

**Which master should you use?** See [Master URLs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) section for all options. The simplest option for testing is `local`, which runs an entire Spark system (driver, master, worker) on your local machine, with no extra configuration.

To set the master through the Scala API:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi").setMaster("local")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 1):

The start of your program just lacks the URL that points to the Spark master endpoint. You can specify this as a command line parameter in InteliJ. The master URL is the URL and port where the Spark master of your cluster is running. An example command line parameter looks like this:

```
-Dspark.master=spark://myhost:7077
```

See the answer to this question for details:
[How to set Master address for Spark examples from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481399/how-to-set-master-address-for-spark-1-x-examples-from-command-line)

Perhaps for your first runs you want to just start a local Spark standalone environment. How to get that running is well documented here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html

If you got this running you can setup your spark master config like this:

```
-Dspark.master=spark://localhost:7077
```

Answer (score 0):

The Master URL need to be set. Using the setMaster("local") function / method solved the issue.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi").setMaster("local")
val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact both @Matthias and @Tzach are right. You should choose your solution based on what is easier for you (maybe prefer the first option for now). As soon as you start running your spark job on a real cluster it is far better to not hardcode the "master" parameter so that you can run your spark job in multiple cluster mode (YARN, Mesos, Standalone with [spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)) and still keep it running locally with Netbeans (-Dspark.master=local[*])