# Where can I set the spark.eventLog.enabled?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I want to test out the machine learning library Mllib form spark and set up a maven project with the dependency in eclipse. When I try to compile [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaLogisticRegressionSummaryExample.java) example I get the following exception: `ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

```
    ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
    at testing.JavaLogisticRegressionSummaryExample.main(JavaLogisticRegressionSummaryExample.java:33)
```

There has been a suggestion to set `spark.eventLog.enabled` too false but where do I set this value?

Comment: Try the JVM Parameter option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481399/how-to-set-master-address-for-spark-1-x-examples-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks for your answer. after adding the parameters I get a  Failed to connect to myhost:7077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in eclipse as java program then you can set master URL like below. When you create a jar with dependency and run in spark using spar-submit then you can pass master url in command. Please refer Spark documentation.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("JavaLogisticRegressionSummaryExample")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")//workaround for issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15899
  .master("local[2]")
  .getOrCreate();
```